# how django browsableapi generate html form automatically?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-templates

i am learning DRF and i am stuck on how DRF serializer generate HTML form in browsableapi. i have UserRegistrationAPIView and UserRegistrationSerializer.

```
class UserRegistrationAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = ()
    permission_classes = ()
    serializer_class = UserRegistrationSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)

        user = serializer.instance
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        data = serializer.data
        data["token"] = token.key

        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

class UserRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, style={'input_type': 'password'})
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, style={'input_type': 'password'})
    confirm_password1 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, style={'input_type': 'password'})

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("id", "username", "email", "password", "confirm_password", "date_joined","confirm_password1")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        del validated_data["confirm_password"]
        del validated_data["confirm_password1"]
        return super(UserRegistrationSerializer, self).create(validated_data)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        if attrs.get('password') != attrs.get('confirm_password'):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Those passwords don't match.")
        return attrs
```

i am confused when i go to url of this view it automatically generate HTML form field. so, does it mean its uses serializer to generate HTML field. Actually, i don't understand the request flow of it how serializer is used to render HTML form. Please help me out or suggest me what to learn first to get on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

DRF response if based on `request.accepted_renderer.format`. If it is html, it returns BrowsableAPI (there are templates, based on bootstrap)